# Why doesn't this recursive jQuery.extend call work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript code, using jquery.extend:

```
hash1 = {"/":{"programme-nav":true}};
hash2 = {"/":{"what-is-scheme":true}};
merged = $.extend(hash1, hash2);
deep_merged =  $.extend(true, hash1, hash2);
//expected_deep_merged = {"/":{"programme-nav":true, "what-is-scheme":true}};
console.log("merged = "+JSON.stringify(merged));
// gives {"/":{"what-is-scheme":true}};
console.log("deep_merged = "+JSON.stringify(deep_merged));
// also gives {"/":{"what-is-scheme":true}};
```

According to the API (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/), passing `true` as the first argument will recursively merge the objects.  In this case, i'd expect to get the result in the comment.  But, i get the same as when i do the non-deep extend.

I've set up a jsfiddle for this here which outputs to the console, https://jsfiddle.net/0725apqn/2/, so you can have a play.

Can anyone explain where i'm going wrong?  thanks, Max

**EDIT:  I am an idiot**.  Passing true as the first argument DOES do the deep merge correctly, but what i didn't notice was that i'd already **overwritten** hash1 in the first part of my example (where i do the non-deep merge), so that when i came to do the "deep" merge, i was actually doing this:

```
deep_merged =  $.extend(true, {"/":{"what-is-scheme":true}}, {"/":{"what-is-scheme":true}});
```

Massive "doh".  thanks anyone who read this.  I'm going to award as many points as possible and then delete this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extend does not make a copy of your data structure, it modifies the one passed as first argument - which is returned by the method.

Tour first call to entend modified 'hash1', which ends up being the same as 'hash2'.

On the second call you are merging two identical hashes.

To achieve what you are aiming for, pass a new instance in the extend parameters.

```
result = $.extend(true, {}, hash1, hash2);
```

This call will not modify 'hash1'

Comment: Passing the extra empty object isn't actually necessary, see my edit.

Comment: It is not necessary - but often convenient :)

Comment: @MaxWilliams You still need the empty object, because otherwise `hash1` will be changed. See: https://jsfiddle.net/6kbm2hma/1/ Implying this wasn't the case by assigning the return value to a new variable will surely be a source of trouble later.

Comment: Ah i see - in this instance i don't mind if the original is changed, but i think you are right that it is better practise to avoid changing the original.